# Can I use an enum in a constructor for a class?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, enums

I am trying to make a class and inside of the class I want to define an enum called Type. Can I use the enum I defined as a constructor for my class? If so, how do I access it outside of the class?

```
class Type {
public:
  enum TType { BLACK, WHITE, GRAY };
  Type(TType type, std::string value);
  ~Type();

...
```

This code doesn't give me any errors but when I try to create an instance of this class in another class it gives me an error because BLACK is not defined:

```
Type piece(BLACK, value);
```

Is there a special way to do this and still have TType as a class constructor for my Type class? This is my first time using enums so I don't know how they work exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
Type piece(Type::BLACK, value);
```

`enum TType` is in scope of `class Type`, so you have to use scope resolution when accessing it outside `Type`'s body and member functions.

Comment: I tried that as well but when I do that it gives me the error: no instance of constructor "Type::Type" matches the argument list argument types are: (Type::TType, string)

Comment: Actually it seems to be a problem with some other part of my code. I'm not sure what it up but in some areas of my code it gives me an error but not others. I will try and figure it out but thanks for the help.

Comment: @greyer no problem, BTW [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/03268b54a952af7c) is a clean example showing no error.